# Perl: How to compare key from one hash with value from another hash?

Tags: perl, hash, key, compare

Ok so I have 2 hashes that look like:

```
%hash1=(name1 => seq1,
        name2 => seq2);

%hash2=(number1 => name1,
        number2 => name2);

%hash3=(number1 => fam1,
        number2 => fam2);
```

I can easily compare the `hash2` and `hash3` based on keys but I need info from `hash1` as well to be added in another output file. Sorry if this sounds too vague. But just let me know how to compare keys from one hash with values from another.

The code looks something like this: Where %tablehash is the hash2 and %newhash is the hash1

```
for my $new_NH(values %tablehash){
    if(exists($newhash{$new_NH})){
        my $taxa_H = $new_NH; #this works
        my $seq_H = $value_NH; #this works too
        my $gi_H=  $somekey;  #this should be the key of table hash, don't know how to access it, I have named it somekey for posting for now
        my $fam_H= $somevalue ;   #this should be the value from another hash3
        print OUTTRIMMED ">fam_H"."_$taxa_H"."_$gi_H\n$seq_H\n\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: compare one key?  compare all keys?  what happens based on the comparison? write some code that does what you want, leaving out just the part you don't know how to do.

Comment: ok I am trying to compare all the keys. It is a part of huge chunk of code, will try to post it right away. On comparison, I need the output  to be something like: >fam1_name1_number1\nseq1 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the keys, not the values.

```
for my $gi_H (keys(%tablehash)) {
   my $taxa_H = $tablehash{$gi_H};
   my $fam_H  = $hash3{$gi_H};

   next if !exists($newhash{$taxa_H});

   my $seq_H = $newhash{$taxa_H};

   printf(OUTTRIMMED ">%s_%s_%s\n%s\n\n",
      $fam_H, $taxa_H, $gi_H, $seq_H);
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think that it's about visual comparison. Good guess, likely you are right. BTW, `s/Question/Quest/`

Comment: @user3849273, Based on the updated question, looks like I was right. He didn't know how to obtain `$number`.

Comment: I should have added that not all the values are present as keys in the hash. It is more like a subset.

Comment: Is that a question? Your updated question demonstrates that you know how to check that.

Comment: Yup I couldn't access the keys! I thought might be doing something wrong! Thanks again guys!